# I have this error Unauthorised admin to execute command mongoose + Graphql

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I used mongoose and Graphql to send my queries to the database but for some reason it doesn't let me create documents. I have tried creating a new user with full admin privileges it hasn't worked I tried changing the default user password but it didn't work.
I rechecked my mongoose model no errors so what might be the problem.
FYI the problem arose with the `return (author.save())` and the database connects normally

### Author Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const authorSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    age: Number
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Author', authorSchema);
```

### schema.js

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const Book = require('../models/book');
const Author = require('../models/Author');
const _ = require('lodash');

const {
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLString,
    GraphQLSchema,
    GraphQLID,
    GraphQLInt,
    GraphQLList
} = graphql;

const BookType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Book',
    fields: ( ) => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        genre: { type: GraphQLString },
        author: {
            type: AuthorType,
            resolve(parent, args){
                //return _.find(authors, { id: parent.authorId });
            }
        }
    })
});

const AuthorType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Author',
    fields: ( ) => ({
        id: { type: GraphQLID },
        name: { type: GraphQLString },
        age: { type: GraphQLInt },
        books: {
            type: new GraphQLList(BookType),
            resolve(parent, args){
                //return _.filter(books, { authorId: parent.id });
            }
        }
    })
});

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
        book: {
            type: BookType,
            args: { id: { type: GraphQLID } },
            resolve(parent, args){
                //return _.find(books, { id: args.id });
            }
        },
        author: {
            type: AuthorType,
            args: { id: { type: GraphQLID } },
            resolve(parent, args){
                //return _.find(authors, { id: args.id });
            }
        },
        books: {
            type: new GraphQLList(BookType),
            resolve(parent, args){
                //return books;
            }
        },
        authors: {
            type: new GraphQLList(AuthorType),
            resolve(parent, args){
                //return authors;
            }
        }
    }
});

const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Mutation',
    fields: {
        addAuthor: {
            type: AuthorType,
            args: {
                name: { type: GraphQLString },
                age: { type: GraphQLInt }
            },
            resolve(parent, args){
                let author = new Author({
                    name: args.name,
                    age: args.age
                });
                return (author.save())
            }
        }
    }
});

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: RootQuery,
    mutation: Mutation
})

;
```

#### error message

```
(node:31482) MongoError: (Unauthorized) not authorized on admin to execute command { 
insert: "authors", documents: [[{name gyfdgyiszukjfheusdzyih} {age 88} {_id 
ObjectID("60af9c682215ea7afad86f4c")} {__v 0}]], ordered: false, writeConcern: { w:
"majority" }
```

Comment: ask me to clarify if you need to

Answer (score 1):

Found this issue, after trying practice by GraphQL tutorial on Youtube.
To solve it, you need to update your mongoose model to the last version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

just update your mongoose to latest version

```
npm uninstall mongoose
npm i mongoose
```